# Merging two arrays into one array, when found duplicates, replace the old one with a new one

Tags: php, array-merge

Hi I am new in PHP and I am trying to merge 2 arrays but I don't want to get duplicates.I have been stuck a week now.
I have first array:

```
$existed_product = array(array('name'=>"pano", 'code'=>"BR0001", 'qty'=>"2", 'price'=>"12"),      
                         array('name'=>"ying", 'code'=>"AB001", 'qty'=>"5", 'price'=>"8"));
```

And I want to merge the second array:

```
$new_product= array('name'=>"pano", 'code'=>"BR0001", 'qty'=>"10", 'price'=>"12");
```

I want to merge them and when it found duplicate product, just replace it with a newer array(has qty=10). The result looks like this:

```
$final_array=array(array('name'=>"pano", 'code'=>"BR0001", 'qty'=>"10", 'price'=>"12"),
                   array('name'=>"ying", 'code'=>"AB001", 'qty'=>"5", 'price'=>"8"));
```

Please help me.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming new product always is a single array, and code is the identifyer, something like this

```
  $existed_product = array( 
    array(
      'name' => 'pano',
      'code' => 'BR0001',
      'qty' => '2',
      'price' => '12' ), 
    array(
      'name' => 'ying',
      'code' => 'AB001',
      'qty' => '5',
      'price' => '8' 
    ) 
  );

  echo '<pre>', print_r( $existed_product, true ), '</pre>';

  $new_product = array(
    'name' => 'pano',
    'code' => 'BR0001',
    'qty' => '10',
    'price' => '12' 
  );

  foreach ( $existed_product as $no => $product ) {
    if ( $new_product['code'] == $product['code'] ) {
      $existed_product[$no]['qty'] = $new_product['qty'];
      $existed_product[$no]['price'] = $new_product['price'];
    }
  }

  echo '<pre>', print_r( $existed_product, true ), '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tom! I have learned a lot from your code.Thanks millions times.

Comment: Very good, learning by example is great ! Makes my time well spent :)